# Executing Java SE Application on Motorola MC70

Tags: java, java-me

I brought a Motorola MC70 Device and my requirement is to execute a swing application (built on Java SE 1.7) on that device. Is this possible and tried a lot over the google and i found things related to Java ME. Please suggest me any solution.

Comment: There is not a whole lot of J2SE support for Windows mobiles. [Mysaifu](http://www2s.biglobe.ne.jp/~dat/java/project/jvm/index_en.html) is one such JVM that supports Windows mobile 5.0. However, I am not sure if it would work if you are using JDK1.7 specific functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

normally you can't run swing code on J2ME devices. However, you may be able to use JavaFX which in Java 8 (not sure about 7) allows embedding Swing components.